# roslyn How to add "#define VAR" on top of C# document

Tags: c#, edit, document, roslyn

I'd like to edit a C# document using roslyn adding a #define trivia on top of it.

For example let's say I have the following

```
namespace MyNameSpace {
 <classes>
}
```

I'd like to make it

```
#define X
namespace MyNameSpace {
 <classes>
}
```

I tried the following:

```
DocumentEditor editor = <get document editor>
var compilationUnit = SyntaxFactory.ParseCompilationUnit("#defin X");
                var defineXTrivia = compilationUnit.GetFirstDirective();
                editor.InsertBefore(editor.OriginalRoot, defineXTrivia);
```

Comment: Go here http://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/ type in `#define VAR` and press the big button. That should help you.

Comment: How did the code you tried fail?

Comment: When I cal
l 
editor.GetChangedDocument() 

it throws 

InvalidOperationException: The item specified is not the element of a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured it out:

```
// Create '#define X' trivia
var defineXDirective = SyntaxFactory.Trivia(SyntaxFactory.DefineDirectiveTrivia("X", isActive : true).NormalizeWhitespace());

// Insert '#define X' trivia on top of the document
var changedRoot = editor.OriginalRoot.WithLeadingTrivia(
                    editor.OriginalRoot.GetLeadingTrivia().InsertRange(0, defineXDirective));
editor.ReplaceNode(editor.OriginalRoot, changedRoot);
```

Comment: Although that works, isn't this easier, for the creation of the defineXDirective?

    var defineXDirective = SyntaxFactory.Trivia(SyntaxFactory.DefineDirectiveTrivia("X", isActive: true).NormalizeWhitespace());

Comment: Indeed, this is quite better, I agree.